# Char array not initializing empty in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

I have a char array to collect names, but the positions are not being initialized empty. 
If any value is entered, the rest of the positions will be empty, but if nothing is entered, some positions will be filled with some "weird" characters.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Don't read uninitialized data?

Comment: Can you share an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Last time i shared a "mcve" they put my question on hold because it had too much information. And not reading is not an option because i want to print how many positions are empty.

Comment: Then it wasn't an MCVE. Also, an array doesn't have empty positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you're initializing the array.  For statically allocated arrays (arrays outside of the function that are not dynamically allocated):

```
char arr[20] = {0};

void function( void ) {
    // stuff happens here to the array
}
```

For automatic arrays (arrays within the scope of a function that are not dynamically allocated):

```
void function( void ) {
   char arr[20] = {0};
   // stuff happens to the array and it cannot 
   // be accessed from the outside the function
}
```

For dynamic arrays, use [calloc()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/) to dynamically allocate and initialize to 0:

```
size_t len = 20;
char *arr = calloc ( len , sizeof(char));
```

You can also use [memset()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) to clear arrays:

```
char arr[20];
memset (arr, 0 , sizeof(arr));
```

Comment: static arrays are default-initialized to zero *anyway*. You're talking about `automatic storage` arrays, I presume?

Comment: Yes, but OP didn't specify where the array was being declared.  I gave the safe option.

Comment: I object to your misuse of the word `static`. It has a well-defined meaning the the context of C, and this is not it. If you want a word for it, that word is `auto`.

Comment: If the op has the array declared outside of the function, it's a static array that's statically allocated.  I'll edit the answer to include both options though.

Comment: Ok, what section (quote) conflicts with what I have said?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80944/discussion-between-eof-and-rost0031).

Comment: @EOF "An object whose identifier is declared ... *either with external or internal linkage* ..., has static storage duration". rost0031's usage is perfectly correct *according to your own citation*. Flagged as offensive.

Comment: @Leushenko: `static` objects have implicit initialization.

Comment: I'm not initializing, i'm just doing "char name[10][40]". If i fill any position, the others are empty. If i don't, some are not.

Comment: @Fuga: where are declaring your array?

Comment: Inside a structure. May that be the problem?

Comment: @Fuga: In that case: Where are you declaring the structure?

Comment: In the very beginning of the code.

Comment: Weird thing i forgot to mention is: it was warking fine, then out of nowhere this started to happen.

Comment: Just edit your post and add your code. This is already on hold for being too broad. This feels like doing a rubic's blindfolded.

Comment: Honestly i won't bodder. There are good people here but some are just a pain in the ass. Last time i edited and no one came to check again, so i'll try to figure it out with the answers i've got so far. Aparently it's harder to make a good question here than solving the problem by yourself. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Clear the array.

```
int i, size=20;
char c[size];

for(i=0; i<size; i++){
    c[i] = '\0'; // or  c[i] = 0; should work as well.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Declaring an array in C allocates a block of memory of the given size and returns a pointer to the first element. So whatever is present in the memory cells is the cause of the "weird" characters.

Always remember that you must always initialize the data and not read uninitialized variables, they always contain garbage values.

You can initialize the array by using

```
char array[12] = {'\0'};
```

`'\0'` is the NUL terminator used to terminate strings in C.

Comment: Explaining the behavior observed by the OP is helpful to understand what is happening here - and avoiding similar mistakes in the future. Good answer IMHO.

Comment: Although the first sentence only applies to dynamic allocation.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, you are correct. I used this example because it is beginner friendly and perhaps the one that is more commonly used.